# How can i set String variable's value with comma(,) in Swift5?

Tags: ios, swift, string, swift5

> Here, my String is FcvZ4eP+ek!y",+Z4E
>   , How can i assign it in strData variable

let strData  = ""

Comment: @ Martin R Sorry to say But my question is not duplicate my String contains + after the comma thats why ' \'  is not working for my string.

Comment: `let strData = #"FcvZ4eP+ek!y",+Z4E"#`

Comment: @LeoDabus Still is not working for me

Comment: print your string and check the result.

Answer (score 1):

```
let strData = "FcvZ4eP+ek!y\",+Z4E"
```

you need to escape any inner quotes

Comment: Sorry but it consider \ as a string

Answer (score 0):

swift

```
let strData = "FcvZ4eP+ek!y\"" + ",+Z4E"
```

Merge multiple string.

Comment: Sorry but it's not working for me i want the exact string like FcvZ4eP+ek!y",+Z4E in your answer i got FcvZ4eP+ek!y,+Z4E

Comment: i update answer, please check in your code. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry it's nt working for me